# Switch all my git repositories to depth 20, to save space?

Tags: bash, shell-script, disk-usage, git, compression

I know that `git clone --depth=20 <repo>` is oftentimes much *much* smaller than `git clone`. [Official docs for `--depth`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---depthltdepthgt).

Looks like I've gone a bit crazy with my repos folder, here's the [`fd`](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd) [piped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) to [`wc`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wc_(Unix)) and [`du`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Du_(Unix)), with output:

```
$ declare -r ALL_GIT="$(fd -HIFt d '.git')"
$ echo "$ALL_GIT" | wc -l
1528
$ echo "$ALL_GIT" | du -hs
du: cannot access './freebsd/contrib/bmake/PSD.doc/tutorial.ms': Permission denied
du: cannot access './freebsd/contrib/bmake/PSD.doc/Makefile': Permission denied
du: cannot access './statsmodels/statsmodels/statsmodels/datasets/macrodata/src/macrodata.xls/macrodata.xls': Permission denied
44G .
```

Is there some command I can use to remove all the history and prune all the orphans, older than `20`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40452701/2072269?

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head I could do the following (put all on one line, remove \):

```
$ fd -HIFt d '.git' -x bash -c 'config_bk="$(mktemp)"; 
                                git_bk="$(mktemp -d)"; \
                                git clone --depth=20 "$0" "$git_bk"; \
                                mv "$0"/.git/config "$config_bk"; \
                                rm -rf "$0"/.git; \
                                mv "$git_bk"/.git "$0";
                                mv "$config_bk" "$0"/.git;' {//}
```

Untested! - For kicks, do a [`df`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Df_(Unix)) before and after, to see how much space is saved.

Problems:

- <s>doesn't looks like I can `git clone` to a particular commit… see this stackoverflow question:
  [How to clone git repository with specific revision/changeset?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3489173)</s> solved through the comment, thanks @stephen-kitt
- not sure what would happen if I've got a bunch of local only branches, stashes, and whatnot

Comment: Re. your second point, you’d lose them (since you’re deleting your original `.git` directory). You could make this quite a bit faster, and clone to a particular commit, by using a local clone; this would also allow you to preserve your local branches, if you wanted to.

Comment: Hey that's a good idea, I keep forgetting about the D and DVCS with git. - Maybe I'll need to really understand everything in the `.git` folder to make headway here…

Answer (score 0):

As per my answer here—based off other answers there—https://stackoverflow.com/a/62650346, and as referred by @muru, here is what works:

```
git pull --depth 20
git tag -d $(git tag -l)
git reflog expire --expire=all --all
git gc --prune=all
```

Want to save space by running this across your entire disk? - Then run this [`fd`](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd) command:

```
fd -HIFt d '.git' -x bash -c 'pushd "$0" && ( git pull --depth 20; git tag -d $(git tag -l); git reflog expire --expire=all --all; git gc --prune=all ) && popd' {//}
```

Or with just regular [`find`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils):

```
find -type d -name '.git' -exec bash -c 'pushd "${0%/*}" && ( git pull --depth 20; git tag -d $(git tag -l); git reflog expire --expire=all --all; git gc --prune=all ) && popd' {} \;
```

What does this mean for me? - Well that aforementioned 44G turned to